# A detail in the proof of the Yoneda lemma

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, yoneda-lemma

In the proof of the Yoneda lemma, Leinster states this ([p. 97](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf)):

> [image: Blockquote]

(The hat is the function $\alpha\mapsto \alpha_A(1_A)$ and the tilde is its inverse.)

But I don't understand how he applies Lemma 1.3.11 above.

> [image]

When applied to the Yoneda lemma, Lemma 1.3.11 says, as far as I understand, that a natural transformation $$\alpha:[\mathscr A^{op},\textbf{Set}](H_{\star},-)\implies -(\star)$$ is a natural isomorphism iff $$\alpha_{(A,X)}:[\mathscr A^{op},\textbf{Set}](H_A,X)\to A(X)$$ is an isomorphism (= bijection in this case).

But it doesn't tell anything about naturality, does it? What am I missing?

And I'm not sure I even understand why "in principle we have to prove naturality of both $(\hat)$ and $(\tilde)$". According to the lemma, if we know $\alpha_{(A,X)}$ is a bijection and that $\alpha$ is a natural transformation (that is, $(\hat)$ is natural), then the result will follow. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Naturality says that certain squares commute. If the horizontal arrows in the squares are isomorphisms, then you can reverse them (thus, reflecting the square) and obtain another commutative square. Therefore if you have a natural transformation whose components are isomorphisms, you can invert all the components to obtain another natural transformation, and it will be the inverse of what you started with. I suppose Leinster’s reference is not to the statement of the lemma per se but rather its proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does : Suppose you manage to prove that the hat transformation is natural.

Then, since you already know that its components are isomorphisms (I assume that was proved earlier on), you know that the hat transformation is *a natural isomorphism*, hence it has an inverse *as a natural transformation*.

But an inverse as a natural transformation must have its components be the inverses of the components, i.e. it has to be the tilde transformation.

So if you prove that the hat transformation is natural, so is its inverse : the tilde transformation.